# Karma/Jasmine - how to stub for a promise and inject in angular 2 - cannot get then()

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I have a stub for router in my tests and a few times I call then afterwards in my code:

```
beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
    const MockRouter = {
        navigate: (x) => ( { then: () => ({x})
        })
    }
```

However, the tests always report back an error:

```
TypeError: this.router.navigate(...).then is not a function
```

I've tried

```
spyOn(routerStub, 'navigate').and.callFake((x) => 'test');
```

but that doesn't work either?

How can make a promise stub so that I can resolve then in my tests?

Comment: Why do you need to stub promise at all? Wouldn't it make more sense to return a promise, eg one created using `Promise.resolve` ?

Comment: Unless you _have_ to use `.then()`, I recommend using [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx). It's easier to read than using `.then()`, and prevents getting into Promise Hell. Sorry I'm not helping in any other way, but it looks like @GeorgeSimms will get you on the right track.

In short, you declare a function prepended by the `async` keyword, and prepend a statement or declaration with the `await` keyword, making each statement or declaration 'blocking', so the program will not move to the next line until the current line of code is finished processing.

Comment: @GeorgeSimms this doesn't work either:

   navigate: (x) => (Promise.resolve({
                then: () => { }
            }))
        };